# JQuery datatable hiding bootstrap dropdown

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm running into an issue that's hiding a bootstrap dropdown when jquery datatable's scrollX property is set to true. See the screenshots below. Any ideas how to fix this while leaving scrollX set to true?

```js
dataTable = $('#table').DataTable({
        "scrollX" : true
})
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
          <li><a href="">Edit</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Delete</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="">Separated link</a></li>

  </ul>
```

Example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/dhL40g04/

Bootstrap dropdown shown when scrollX = false
[image]

Bootstrap dropdown hidden when scrollX = true
[image]

Comment: Ideally, I'd like it to behave the same as the menu with scrollX set to false

Comment: Multiple, one per row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#table .dropdown-menu {
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    width: 160px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/dhL40g04/2/)**

If you want the menu to work without resizing the table, you'll need to move the markup for it outside the table. You could use absolute positioning to gain the same location.

Comment: This is very close - this does resolve the problem of the menu getting hidden. The only side effect is that it ends up expanding the table row fit around the menu. Any ideas to get around that?